# display user contents with php

Tags: php

[image]

i'm writing simple program that allow user to write their contents and post them

i'm using php ,html,css and mysql database

assume user has written a content in this format

[image: see the screen shot]

i know codes written in php will allow user to post and store contents in database

i will use `<?php echo $row['content']; ?>` to display content posted by the user

but contents are not displayed in similary format as it was written by the use in paragraph formats(in format of more than one paragraph),insetad it display like this

Python datatypes.....To get Python handwritten notes, visit the link in the bio.....Visit our site for free project source codes-- copyassignment.com.....Turn on post notifications for more such posts like this.....Follow @python.hub for more content on computer science,

what's the good idea on this problem ? how can i solve it so that contents should be displayed as it is written by the user,,,

any help will be appreciated

```
<?php
 require_once 'dbconfig.php';
 
 if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
 {
  $content = $_POST['content'];// user email
  
   $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO template(content) VALUES(:content)');
   $stmt->bindParam(':content',$content);
   $stmt->execute();
 }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
  
   <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
      <form method="post">
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Description</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="content"></textarea>
</div>
           <button type="submit" name="btnsave">ok</button>
           </form>
           <div>
           <div>
           <div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo nl2br($row['content']); ?>
```

Use nl2br to convert Input/textarea linebreaks to real html linebreaks (br).